# Like button stripping URL GET parameters

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, url-parameters

I am trying to set up a like button to like a specific element so the site responds accordingly when a user follows the link.

I am trying to use XFBML method but have tried the others too - none have worked.

This is an example of what I have been trying.

```
<fb:like href="http://www.example.com/dir/shared.php?user=4244&action=t39s&fb=1" send="false" layout="button_count" width="450" show_faces="false"></fb:like>
```

I have tried it both urlencoded and unencoded.

I'm sure it's something simple that I'm missing but I've been unable to work it out after loads of investigation.

Comment: Put your URL through the debug tool first, and see what it says: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: thanks, I didn't know that tool existed, turns out the page had a canonical link rel that was breaking it.